# Netbeans: C++ Successful Build, Run Failed

Tags: c++, vector, netbeans

UPDATE / SOLUTION: It seems this is a problem with Netbeans and not my code. I switched form NetBeans to CodeBlocks and use another Compiler and it works.

I'm trying to write my own Vector class in c++ at the moment. For this I am still using the built in vector, but I want to define my own operators. My problem is that building my project works (**"Build successful"**), but when I try to run my project it just says **"Run failed"** in the console. I have no idea what might be causing this error and the internet has not provided a solution yet. I'm using NetBeans Apache on Windows 10. Here is my code:

**Vector.hh**

```
#ifndef VECTOR_HH
#define VECTOR_HH

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Vector{
public:
    Vector();
    ~Vector();

    Vector(const Vector&);
    Vector(int d, double v);
    Vector(int d);

    Vector& operator=(const Vector&);
    double& operator[](const int);
    double operator[](const int) const;

    Vector& operator+(const Vector&);
    Vector& operator-(const Vector&);
    Vector& operator*(const double);

    double operator*(const Vector&);

    double norm();
    friend Vector& operator*(const double, Vector& v);

private:
    int dimension;
    vector<double>* values;
};

#endif /* VECTOR_HH */
```

**Vector.cc**

```
#include "Vector.hh"
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

Vector::Vector():dimension(0){
    values = new vector<double>();
}

Vector::~Vector(){
    dimension = 0;
    delete values;
}

Vector::Vector(const Vector& v):dimension(v.dimension){
    values = new vector<double>();
    for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
        values->push_back(v[i]);
    }
}

Vector::Vector(int d, double v):dimension(d){
    values = new vector<double>();
    values->assign(dimension, v);
}

Vector::Vector(int d):dimension(d){
    values = new vector<double>();
    values->assign(dimension, 0);
}

Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& v){
    dimension = v.dimension;
    delete values;
    values = new vector<double>();
    for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
        values->push_back(v[i]);
    }
    return *this;
}

Vector& Vector::operator*(double s){
    Vector* v = new Vector(dimension);
    for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
        (*v)[i] = s * values->at(i);
    }
    return *v;
}

double& Vector::operator[](const int i){
    return values->at(i);
}

double Vector::operator[](const int i) const{
    return values->at(i);
}

Vector& Vector::operator+(const Vector& v){
    Vector* u = new Vector(dimension);
    for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
        (*u)[i] = v[i] + values->at(i);
    }
    return *u;
}

Vector& Vector::operator-(const Vector& v){
    Vector* u = new Vector(dimension);
    for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
        (*u)[i] = v[i] - values->at(i);
    }
    return *u;
}

double Vector::operator*(const Vector& v){
    double d = 0;
    if(v.dimension != dimension) return 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
        d = d + v[i] * values->at(i);
    }
    return d;
}

double Vector::norm(){
    double d = (*this) * (*this);
    return sqrt(d);
}

Vector& operator*(const double s, Vector& v){
    return v * s;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Vector.hh"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Hello there";
    Vector v(2);
    v[0] = 3;
    v[1] = -4;

    Vector u(2);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Does NetBeans have a built in debugging functionality? I'm not familiar with it so I don't know, myself.

Comment: I tagged for NetBeans since this may have nothing to do with the code and everything to do with the project setup.

Comment: The code runs alright in Visual Studio 2019 so it must be a Netbeans issue. Do you have an option to clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: Why is `values` a pointer?

Comment: You should not be using `new` so much – you have plenty of memory leaks. You can implement this without using it even once.

Comment: Netbeans has a debugger, when I run it the following message comes up: `During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.`

About the pointer thing: I'm pretty new to object design in C++. I thought this might be the way to go, because then I could define an useful destructor for my object... Do you think this might cause the problem?

Comment: I tried cleaning the project, that did not change anything. I even tried just copying the code and just creating a new porject with that

Comment: This `0xc0000139` tells you that you have a problem with your runtime for your compiler. You have a missing dll.

Comment: Do you know a quick way to fix this or why it occurs? Becuase I have other projects that run successfully.

Comment: Update your question with the messages (if any) that get written to the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) when you run your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve the problem using NetBeans, but switching to another IDE and Compiler (CodeBlocks in my case) helped and now the code is running seamlessly.